# buffered Op-amplifier

Tags: bandwidth, phase, cadence

I am trying to simulate a buffer with an op-amp using CMOS, I am using Cadence. The phase margin I am getting is negative (not stable) about -272 deg, I am trying to reach 50 deg for a gain of 86 and BW 0f 73MHz. how can I fix this?

[image: 3]

Comment: Why do you think this can even be answered if you do not include **a schematic**. What do you know about poles, zeros and impulse responses? How do you determine the phase margin? -200 degrees sound silly are you sure it isn't +160 degrees?

Comment: You haven't got the scale for the magnitude either - it looks like you have nowhere near enough bandwidth. As @Bimpelrekkie states, you haven't given anywhere near enough information for anyone to help.